# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, orm

StackTrace

```
he last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

May 14, 2015 6:58:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/spring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:205)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2162)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2148)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1903)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:429)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.list(Unknown Source)
at net.codejava.spring.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

PFA my StackTrace. I don't know why i am getting this error. I have also imported sqljdbc jar in my configuration file.

Comment: can show the config file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: `Connection refused: connect` - your DB won't let you connect. You're ether connecting to the wrong server (i.e. production server in dev config) or you need to configure your DB to grant you access.